# How to flag a page I can't access

Tags: discussion, support

I was a bit surprised when I tried to look at this question [Is there a Shorter way - SQL - multiple LIKE and OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52563952/is-there-a-shorter-way-sql-multiple-like-and-or) today to see the following message from `Norton Internet Security`:

[image]

Is this something that SO has put on the page? If not, how can I flag it for moderator attention when I can't (well ok, could, but don't want to) access the page?

Comment: Dunno who would block that; they basically just collect internet traffic data. (And why would it block the whole page for that one request?)

Comment: @StephenLeppik Norton is nothing if not paranoid. But I find it odd that this is the only page out of thousands I have viewed on SO where I've seen this.

Comment: You wouldn't flag this for moderator attention. This is not something the moderators can do anything about. Posting here to get advice is fine.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks for that. Since it doesn't occur on any other SO page I have visited, I was presuming it was something inside either the question or one of the answers, which I was why I thought it might require moderator attention.

Comment: There is no reference to pixel.quantserve on that page. Norton (or your ISP) is broken.

Comment: @DavidPostill I can now happily access that page without any warnings from Norton so either any references have been removed or Norton was having some sort of brain fade. I guess I'll never know...

Comment: It is just your anti-malware product reminding you to not uninstall it. Users might if it never says anything :) Why SO uses quantserve is [explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6037/pixel-quantserve-com-whats-it-about-and-should-i-block-it).  Not so sure it is still relevant, on my machine it gets blocked by AdBlock.

Comment: @DavidPostill StackOverflow performs requests to `pixel.quantserve.com` at least in some geos, so that part seems to refer to legitimate activity.